# Is there a faster alternative to R 'apply' function on rows?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, apply

I would like to calculate the standard deviation for each row on a subset of columns. I am using a data table of more than 1 700 000 rows and the function 'apply'.

The line code below takes time :

```
apply(as.matrix(data[ , .SD, .SDcols = subset_of_columns]), 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Is there an alternative ?

Thank you.

Comment: You could maybe take a look into parallelization http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html

Comment: `rowSds` from `matrixStats`

Comment: This works fine : system time of 0.014 instead of 0.270) ! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that top @minem, that is awesome!

Comment: `melt` the data.table and use something like `DT[, sd(values), by = rowid]`.